Convolution of a 3D function with the 3D Laplace operator
In the context of quantum mechanics I need an uncommon operator.
Let us start by the definition of the 3D convolution I need (integration over the whole 3D space):
$$ g(\boldsymbol{r}) * f(\boldsymbol{r}) = \int d^3 r' g(\boldsymbol{r} - \boldsymbol{r'}) f(\boldsymbol{r'}) $$
For instance we have this famous convolution product for electron-electron repulsion operator:
$$  \frac{1}{r} * f(\boldsymbol{r}) = \int d^3 r' \frac{f(\boldsymbol{r'})}{\Vert \boldsymbol{r} - \boldsymbol{r'} \Vert} $$
which is just a scalar function of the space variable $\boldsymbol{r}$. Now let us take the 3D Laplacian, defined in Cartesian coordinates by:
$$ \Delta = \partial_x^2 + \partial_y^2 + \partial_z^2 $$
Question
Let us define the operator $L$ by:
$$ L = f(\boldsymbol{r}) * \Delta = \int d^3 r' f(\boldsymbol{r} - \boldsymbol{r'}) \Delta_{\boldsymbol{r'}} $$
Is there a simple expression of this new operator (in terms of derivatives for instance) ? The function $f$ is integrable (and also square integrable but I do not care) on the 3D space, can be complex but we can restrict it in the real case.
Thanks for reading
Hint:
It is obvious but if $f = \delta(\boldsymbol{r}) $ (Dirac delta) so we have:
$$ L = \delta(\boldsymbol{r})* \Delta = \Delta $$
